# 3D plot of part of hyperboloid

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I would like to plot a 3D figure of a hyperbole that is cut down at the bottom of it in the following way (figure)

any ideas?[image]

Comment: FYI, a [conic section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) is something else entirely. You'll get more relevant views if you change the title to reflect this. Also, the figure you show is not a cone but a paraboloid. Which one do you want to plot?

Comment: tnx, changed it, and it's suppose to be an hyperbole

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's my stab at your problem. This is the experimental script I've been using:

```
%%# first part    
%#------------------

clf

%# use cylinder to get unit cone
[x,y,z] = cylinder( linspace(1, 0, 1e3), 1e3);

%# intersect the cone with this surface
inds = z < (cos(x).*sin(pi*y/2)+1)/4;

x(inds) = NaN; %# remove all corresponding 
y(inds) = NaN; %# indices, in all arrays
z(inds) = NaN;

%# Now plot the cone. Note that edges are ugly when 
%# using a large number of points
surf(x, y, z, 'edgecolor', 'none');

%%# second part
%#------------------

hold on

%# the surface to intersect the cone with
f = @(x,y) (cos(x).*sin(pi*y/2)+1)/4;

%# add the surfacfe to the cone plot
[x,y] = meshgrid( linspace(-1,1, 1e3) );
surf(x,y, f(x,y), 'edgecolor', 'none')
```

The first part shows a cone intersected with a curve. You might want to tinker a bit with the curve to get the overall shape right, which is what the second part is for.

If you want a paraboloid (or other), just use

```
[x,y] = meshgrid( linspace(-1,1, 1e3) );
z = 1-x.^2-y.^2;  %# or whatever other equation
```

instead of the `cylinder` command.

Comment: @jarhead huh? Works fine here...What did you see then?

Comment: the second part is unnecessary and for an hyperbole: z=c*sqrt(1+(x/a).^2+(y/b).^2), but tnx for the help, I worked it out

Comment: @jarhead Just to clear a few misunderstandings: I already mentioned the second part is useless, other than to "design" the function for the wavy-part. And a *hyperbole* is a curve, whereas a *hyperboloid* is the surface you describe. And I didn't know your values for `c`, `a` and `b`, so I just gave you a simple paraboloid as an example. Anyway, glad it works now, glad to help :)